# Getting full text with children/grandchildren in XPath/XSL

Tags: xslt, text, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm using an XSL 1.0 stylesheet, and I've got a node similar to the following:

```
<p>Hello, <b>John</b>, how are you?</p>
```

I'm currently in an xsl:template matched against the `<p>` node.  I want to create an xsl:variable that ends up with the string value "Hello, John, how are you?".

The `text()` function fails here, as it only returns "Hello, , how are you?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely to be more efficient just to take the string value of the current node

```
 <xsl:variable name="x">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 <xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm currently in an xsl:template matched against the `<p>` node. I want
>   to create an xsl:variable that ends up with the string value "Hello,
>   John, how are you?".

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vSomeName" select="string(.)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Duh, I solved it. :)

```
descendant-or-self::text()
```

Comment: There are two better and simpler solutions then this. Maybe you could learn something from them?

Comment: Cool, definitely good to know alternatives (and probably more "correct" alternatives).  Thanks!